# Which honeycombs produce beeswax?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods, minecraft-forestry

I have an automatic system for several tipe of combs I want to procces. But I need to know which combs produce beeswax because I need to sort them out of the system.

Which combs produce beeswax?

I would like to get as much beeswax a possible for making differend casts. I have loads of differend bees but I need to know which of them make beeswax

Comment: Can't you just use **Not Enough Items** to find this out ?

Comment: There is a bug in the minecraft pack that makes it so it does not show carpe ter centrifuge and squeezer recepies

Comment: Which pack & version is it ?

Comment: Mindcrack pack 1.4.7 I wrote the wrong thing...

Answer (score 2):

According to this [wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Beeswax), most combs produce bees wax. The easiest to get your hands on is probably the common *Honey Comb*, though.